# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for a local project Source Package?

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I have been struggling A LOT with this problem.
I'm working on a netbeans java project with a lot of packages, and at first I changed the gui but when I run the code it didn't reflect any changes even though I used compile on save, clean, clean and compile targets among other things. Then I read something about reflection and binary maps and someone in that thread suggested I changed the Package name, and I did and the program started reflecting my changes on the gui.
I have worked changing the Package name every time I worked on a new java file on said Package, but now I'm getting a error which I cannot solve this way...

This is where the issue is thrown

```
private void AccederActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        us = val.nomUsr(Juser.getText());
```

And this is the stacktrace of the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: operaciones.Validacion.nomUsr(Ljava/lang/String;)Lobjetos/Usuario;
    at gui.Inicio.AccederActionPerformed(Inicio.java:1122)
    at gui.Inicio.JcontrasenaActionPerformed(Inicio.java:1100)
    at gui.Inicio.access$100(Inicio.java:40)
    at gui.Inicio$2.actionPerformed(Inicio.java:227)
```

In the IDE it doesn't return any compiling issues, such as wrong name reference, etc. and of course the java file "Validacion" exists inside the "operaciones" package and it has a method called nomUsr, this is the summary code of the method:

```
public class Validacion {
    ConexionBD con;

    /**Constructor
    @param con database connection*/
    public Validacion(ConexionBD con){
        this.con=con;
    }

    public Usuario nomUsr(String usr){             
            //buscar en la base de datos el nombre del usuario
            UsuarioBD us = new UsuarioBD(con);
            Usuario usuario =us.nomUsr(usr);
            return usuario;
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Ljava/lang/String` represent an array of String. Your method expect a string instead. There is no existing `nomUsr` method that receive an array of string in parameter.

```
public Usuario nomUsr(String usr)
```

Either change the definition of your method, or change `Juser.getText()` to return a string.

Comment: That is a weird error too. Because I just run the project in debugging mode and now it runs fine with the same String. Instead in returns new errors

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clases.Calculo.getHrs_ganadas_mat()F
 at reporte.CalculoEf.lista_calculos(CalculoEf.java:800)
 at reporte.CalculoEf.CalcularDia_Mod(CalculoEf.java:2334)
 at reporte.CalculoEf.CalcularDia_CC(CalculoEf.java:2430)
 at reporte.RepEficiencia.jBAcpetarRepEfActionPerformed(RepEficiencia.java:587)
 at reporte.RepEficiencia.access$100(RepEficiencia.java:56)
 at reporte.RepEficiencia$2.actionPerformed(RepEficiencia.java:179)`

Comment: I debugged too and I send a float to getHrs_ganadas_mat() such as specified by the method, the float value is initialized and the Calculo class is under clases package and has a method getHrs_ganadas_mat() which returns a float (a simple getter I won't include here)